# Are pipe reads atomic on Linux (multiple writers, one reader)?

Tags: c, linux, pipe, named-pipes

I have multiple processes (and multiple threads within some processes) writing to a single named pipe.  The pipe is opened with `O_WRONLY` for each writer.

I have another process reading from this pipe, blocking with `select`.  The pipe is opened with `O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK` in the reader.

When `select` in the reader wakes up, will `read` return at most one chunk of data available, or could it return multiple chunks?  If the former, then I expect after I read the first chunk, `select` will immediately wake up until I finish reading the remaining chunks.

Or could `read` return less than one of the chunks written by a writer?

I'm writing and reading strings, and they're all less than `PIPE_BUF`, so I know the writes are atomic.  I can easily append a delimiter to check for multiple strings, but I'm just curious how it works on Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`read` will return all data available in the pipe, it doesn't matter how many `write`s were used to write that data. The number of bytes returned will be same as the size requested, when there is more data in pipe. In such cases, `select` will return immediately, indicating that there is some data to read.

You will have to delimit each chuck you write to pipe and separate it after reading.